# Clicking on a tag to get event on sibling tag

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have the following html

```html
<ul id="report">
  <li class="suite">
    <h1>Level 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="test pass fast">
        <h2>it first</h2>
        <pre style="display: none;">
          <code>('hello').should.be.a('string');</code>
        </pre>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the pre style from display:block to display:none when the h2 tag above it is clicked. But, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. I know I need to do something along the lines of:

```js
function changeStyle() {
    pre.style.display = 'none' == pre.style.display
    ? 'block'
    : 'none';
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to attach it to the h2. I've tried:

```js
var h2 = getElementsByTagName('h2');
var pre = h2.getElementById('pre');
```

But that isn't right since pre is not a child of h2. I'm not sure what to do. I tried adding a variety of click event listeners to h2 and calling the changeStyle function.

Note: I would really prefer not to have to use jQuery.

Edit: Alright, so I'm not crazy. I have tried almost all of these methods before posting this question and they didn't work. There has to be something else going on here.

For example, I tried Josh Beam's method and I get: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" error.

I even tried wrapping it with

```
document.onLoad = function () {
//code
}
```

and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why not wrap them in a div, get that parent div, then search down for the `pre`?

Comment: Thanks for the responses all! Unfortunately it seems like my answer (and problem) is in another castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure you're getting the sibling `pre` element, just do this (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t89vb06h/1)):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var pre = e.target.nextElementSibling;

    pre.style.display = pre.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

This will make sure you're not selecting any other `pre` elements that might be present on the page.

Comment: I marked this one as the answer because it most closely and elegantly accomplishes what I was trying to do. Unfortunately I am encountering another problem at a higher level that I do not understand. I'll post another question about that.

Answer (score 1):

Will work for any H2 element inside `ul#report`

```
var main_ul = document.querySelector("#report");

main_ul.onclick = function(event){
  var elm = event.target;

  if(elm.tagName === "H2"){
    var pre = elm.nextElementSibling; // tada magic!
    changeStyle(pre);
  }
};
```

Comment: I did not mention that the h2 elements are sometimes nested into multiple list.suites.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `getElementsByTagName` like this:

```js
var flag = 0
document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].onclick = function() {
  if (flag == 1) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].style.display = "none";
    flag = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].style.display = "block";
    flag = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="report">
  <li class="suite">
    <h1>Level 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="test pass fast">
        <h2>it first</h2>
        <pre style="display: none;">
          <code>('hello').should.be.a('string');</code>
        </pre>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will also allow you to toggle the `display`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var report = document.getElementById("report"); // <--- get the parent 
var h2 = report.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];  // <--- search for h2 within parent
var pre = report.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];// <--- search for pre within parent
h2.addEventListener('click', function(){        // <--- attach event to h2
  pre.style.display = pre.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';  // <--- toggle display
});
```

```js
var report = document.getElementById("report");
var h2 = report.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
var pre = report.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];
h2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pre.style.display = pre.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<ul id="report">
  <li class="suite">
    <h1>Level 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="test pass fast">
        <h2>it first</h2>
        <pre style="display: none;">
          <code>('hello').should.be.a('string');</code>
        </pre>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```